# How to create a section of StaticTableView with variable row?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Basically I have a view controller with a static table view with 2 sections. The first section will have 1 row and represent a main category.

I want the second section to have a variable amount of rows depending on how many entries the user has for that category. So if the category is "Activities" and they have "Baseball, softball" as activities, I want there to be 2 rows in that section.

How do you do this? It keeps crashing when I code it.

Comment: "It keeps crashing when I code it.". Show us the code you have written that results in a crash, and maybe we can help you correct it. Show everything relevant, including your table design. Show us your data model that will control what you're trying to make dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.....

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  if section == 0 {
    return 1
  } else {
    return YourDataSource.count
  }
}
```

and on your cellforrowatindex

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            //Do your stuff for the static section
        } else {
            //Do your stuff for the dynamic section
        }
}
```

Comment: so I tried what you have first there - but what do I put under the "attributes" for the section in main.storyboard? when the number is different from the "return Your DateSource.count" the app crashes

Comment: which attributes are you trying to setup?

Comment: in the interfacebuilder when i click on the section in the static table view, there are attributes for "rows" "header" and "footer." "rows" needs to be the same value as what is in my code, otherwise the app crashes when I try and access the table view

Comment: You mean the height, and estimate height for Table view, sections under the "Show the size Inspector" in Xcode??
That should make your app crash, you are crashing somewhere else, whats the crash error you are getting??